# slurm job script for iterative loops

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, openmp, slurm

I use a bash script like this,

```
for i in  0 1 2 3 4 5 do  

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$((2 **i)) 
&& ./debug > ./logs/112500/exp$1/log-$((2 **i)).txt    

done
```

Now I need to run this script 32 times for empirical purposes. I have a slurm job script as below, but it performs in a strange way. To keep the semantics same as the above, I want srun to run my binary and finish, then continue with 2 threads and so on, until experiment 2nd starts. So every experiment runs at a time. In each experiment every srun needs to run at a time as well.

However what really happens is, 32 experiments kind of run sequentially, but by only executing first srun each time which is with 1 thread count, and its log file (log-1.txt)s is created. When I insert echo between sruns, they get printed, but not srun bash -c echos. Other sruns after the first srun are not being executed at all, although the experiment loop iterates through 32. I wonder why this happens and look for a solution.

```
`#!/bin/bash`
`#SBATCH -p cs`
`#SBATCH -e %j.err`
`#SBATCH --time=05:00`
`#SBATCH --output=slurm-%j.out`

`#executable`

`for I in $(seq 32);`
`do`
`mkdir ./logs/112500/exp$I`
`export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`
`echo "Launching command for ./logs/112500/exp$I/log-1.txt"`
`srun --nodes=1 --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=1  bash -c "./debug > ./logs/112500/exp$I/log-1.txt"`
`export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2`
`srun --nodes=1 --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=2  bash -c "./debug > ./logs/112500/exp$I/log-2.txt"`
`export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4`
`srun --nodes=1 --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=4  bash -c "./debug > ./logs/112500/exp$I/log-4.txt"`
`export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8`
`srun --nodes=1 --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=8 bash -c  "./debug > ./logs/112500/exp$I/log-8.txt"`
`export OMP_NUM_THREADS=16`
`srun --nodes=1 --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=16 bash -c "./debug > ./logs/112500/exp$I/log-16.txt"`
`export OMP_NUM_THREADS=32`
`srun --nodes=1 --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=32 bash -c "./debug > ./logs/112500/exp$I/log-32.txt"`
`done`
```

slurm job scripts, sequential sruns, only one srun executes

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just solved the case. Missing header information on the resource allocation caused some trouble for following sruns because they want to allocate more than the default (ntasks=1) resource.